# How does function-like macros work, this example

Tags: c, macros, embedded

```
void someOtherFunction(void)
{
    ...
}


//Is it possible to call the #define like this, in the global scope? When does the execution come here?
SYSTEM_CONTROL_REGISTER_INIT_FUNCTION( credHandlerInit, LEVEL_APPLICATION, SYSTEM_CONTROL_ORDER_DONT_CARE ); 

void credHandlerInit(void)
{
    portBASE_TYPE result;

    result = xTaskCreate( credHandlerTask,
                        (portCHAR *) MBS_CFG_TASK_NAME_CRED_HANDLER,
                        MBS_CFG_TASK_STACK_CRED_HANDLER,
                        NULL,
                        MBS_CFG_TASK_PRIO_CRED_HANDLER,
                        &credHandlerTaskHandle );

}
```

and in a .h-file the following macro is defined:

```
#define SYSTEM_CONTROL_REGISTER_INIT_FUNCTION( _initFunctionName,                                                       \
                                               _initLevel,                                                              \
                                               _initOrder )                                                             \
                                                                                                                        \
    void _initFunctionName( void );                                                                                     \
                                                                                                                        \
    SystemControlInitListRecord const systemControlInitRecord_ ## _initLevel ## _initOrder ## _ ## _initFunctionName    \
                    __attribute__ ((section (".systemControlInitList")))                                                \
                    = {                                                                                                 \
                        .name                   = #_initFunctionName,                                                   \
                        .syncedInitFunction     = NULL,                                                                 \
                        .unsyncedInitFunction   = _initFunctionName,                                                    \
                        .level                  = _initLevel,                                                           \
                        .order                  = _initOrder,                                                           \
                        .initType               = SYSTEM_CONTROL_RTOS_RUNNING                                           \
                      };                                                                                                \
                                                                                                                        \
    void _initFunctionName( void )
```

What I don't understand is how this function is called?
I do not see any call to this function in the code.
Can someone explain how this work?

Is the code below valid, calling the macro like this?

```
//main.c

#define SOMETHING(x) (someVariable = x)

static uint32_t someVariable;

SOMETHING(5);

int main(void)
{
  printf("%d", someVariable); //should print 5 here then?
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation of your C compiler. Try [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), read its documentation and read the documentation of [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) which explains your code. If allowed to use GCC on your `translation-unit.c`, invoke it (e.g. as `gcc -Wall -H -I/usr/local/include/ -O -C -E translation-unit.c > translation-unit.i`) to get the preprocessed form, and look inside that `translation-unit.i` with an editor (e.g. [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)...)

Comment: For your next question, provide some [mre] and give the compilation command. Before, refer to [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website. You may also want to read some C standard, like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or better

Comment: You could also read the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book. It has chapters dedicated to the preprocessor (in particular §16)

Comment: This pretty much looks like a tutorial of how to _not_ write function-like macros. Since the function-like macro call doesn't match the number of parameters used by the macro, there's no making sense of the code either. Is this a copy/paste of the real code?

Comment: Yep copied the wrong macro. Now it should be the correct one

Comment: So my question is, how is it possible to call the #define from the line between the "someOtherFunction()" and "credHandlerInit()" in the global scope? Is this correct?
This is actual code from a code-base Im working on. Very confusing with all function-like macros

Comment: The original code doesn't contain the `void credHandlerInit(void)` on the caller side either, now does it?

Comment: No it didn't, but that was actual code aswell. But I took this one to clarify a bit

Comment: The `void credHandlerInit(void)` on the caller side collides with `void _initFunctionName( void)` in the macro, these do the same thing. So this code wouldn't compile. Can you please copy/paste the actual code that compiles?

Comment: Oh nevermind, it's the macro that's crappily written. Whoever wrote it made a function declaration twice.

Comment: Look at the code, the call to the #define passes the credHandlerInit function as an argument, then this argument is used to call it.

Comment: Mmhm. I posted an answer. If this is part of some RTOS source, please name them so we can shame them in public on the Internet.

Comment: thanks Lundin. See my latest post above.

Answer (score 1):

The intention of this code is the following:

- The macro declares a function named `credHandlerInit`. This name is passed to the `_initFunctionName` macro parameter name. Whoever wrote the macro didn't quite know what they are doing, so we end up with two function declarations `void credHandlerInit(void );`, which is OK but very fishy. Perhaps they optionally meant the macro to be followed by the function definition in the form of `{ ... }`. At any rate, not the best idea.
- The whole `SystemControlInitListRecord const` part declares a read-only struct of that type, then names it `systemControlInitRecord_LEVEL_APPLICATION_SYSTEM_CONTROL_ORDER_DONT_CARE _credHandlerInit`. This is where I'd start to suspect that the programmer who wrote this is paid per letter written... and also that they were not an expert at C programming.

  NOTE: identifiers longer than 32 characters is a safety hazard in C, see 5.2.4.1 translation limits. So if this function name will act as an external identifier, which we have all the reasons to believe since it ain't `static`, a conforming compiler may not be able to distinguish between different functions with the `systemControlInitRecord_LEVEL_APPLICATION_` prefix. There's no guarantee of "name mangling" but the compiler might end up generating source that calls the wrong function from the external caller side.

  In practice, modern compilers tend to distinguish between far more than 32 characters, but they aren't guaranteed to do so. Best case scenario, the code is non-portable between standard compilers. Worst case, the whole code will go completely haywire on the designated compiler.

  So this is a subtle and severe bug who the original programmer was not aware of. Someone will need to slap 'em from inventing such ridiculously long identifier names. It is both dangerous and completely unreadable.
- The `__attribute__ ((section (".systemControlInitList")))` is a common non-standard extension used by gcc and a bunch of other compilers for creating custom memory segments. These names need to correspond to a memory section in the linker script. Why this variable needs to reside in that memory section, I don't know, but this is obviously part of some embedded system where named memory sections are quite common practice (used for bootloaders, on-chip library code, NVM variables, ISRs, flash drivers etc etc).
- The whole `{ .name = #_initFunctionName,  .syncedInitFunction = NULL, ...` part is a struct initializer list utilizing _designated initializers. The first member is apparently a string and the `#` "stringification" operator turns the name string into `"credHandlerInit"`.
- The `void _initFunctionName( void )`, as already mentioned, might optionally begin the function definition, which is then apparently expected to continue on the caller-side. Or otherwise the `;` in the macro call makes this a 2nd function declaration.

As you can hopefully tell from my comments, this code is very badly written by someone obsessing in making things as needlessly complicated as possible, whereas the truly good C programmers try to make things as simple as possible.

I would guess it is part of some smelly RTOS source and used for user-side task creation or similar? I would stay clear of this source, since there's lots of code smell and I already found one severe bug from just reading one single macro.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. But it doesn't really explain how it ends up in the #define in the header-file. What happens on the line between the two functions? Is that the "call" to the macro?

Comment: @Bei Yes it is the macro call which does all the things from the bullet list in the answer.

Comment: thanks. Look at my answer below and the question (not able to post code in a good way here)

Comment: @Bei Well yeah of course that macro is valid, although bad practice. I'd recommend reading about macro basics in a C book before tackling more advanced code such as this mess.

Comment: the thing is, I haven't written this crap. Im working on an excisting code-base and just trying to understand this old-school coding style. I've even seen "goto" in the code. Feels a bit ancient

Comment: @Bei It's not old, just bad. Designated initializers are fairly modern practice, introduced in C99.

Answer (score 0):

A "function-like macro" just means a macro which takes arguments.

In this example you have a macro which takes arguments but it is not being used like a function at all.

This macro expands to a constant object definition.  The object is a structure with information about a function and when to call it.  The object is placed in a custom non-standard section called ".systemControlInitList".

In order to use this code you must have a corresponding custom linker control script (usually called something.ld).  This will collect all the objects that are placed in the custom section and put them somewhere in the program image, probably ROM.  It will put some custom symbol at the the start of the block of such objects, and probably another symbol at the end.

There will then need to be some custom code that runs as part of your application start or boot sequence that looks for that symbol and executes all the functions referred to by the array of structure.